# Python seaborn plots: having a small issue while writing a function for bar plots

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to write a function for bar plots with the following:

```py
def bar_plot(data, x, y, title):
    sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    data = data.sort_values(ascending=False, by=x)
    data = data.head(n=10)
    if data[x].any() > 1000000:
        data[x] = data[x] / 1000000
        ax = sns.catplot(data=data, x=x, y=y, kind='bar')
        ax.set_xlabels(x + ' ($ Millions)', size=15)
        plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
        ax.set_ylabels(y, size=15)
        ax.fig.suptitle(title, size=35)
    else:
       ax = sns.catplot(data=data, x=x, y=y, kind='bar')
       ax.set_xlabels(x, size=15)
       plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
       ax.set_ylabels(y, size=15)
       ax.fig.suptitle(title, size=35)
```

I want it to work with a couple of different dataframes that I am working with. I have some dataframes with a lot of large values and some with small values. I'd like to divide by a million for those dataframes with large values to make the graph easier to read. My original understanding was that `data[x].any() > 1000000` would find any row in the dataframe that is over a million and return `True` and then run through the `if` statement. However, even when the dataframe clearly has values well over a million, it is skipping to the `else` statement.

While trying to figure out the problem, I reversed the `if` statement by looking for values under a million:

```py
def bar_plot(data, x, y, title):
    sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    data = data.sort_values(ascending=False, by=x)
    data = data.head(n=10)
    if data[x].any() < 1000000:
        ax = sns.catplot(data=data, x=x, y=y, kind='bar')
        ax.set_xlabels(x, size=15)
        plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
        ax.set_ylabels(y, size=15)
        ax.fig.suptitle(title, size=35)
    else:
        data[x] = data[x] / 1000000
        ax = sns.catplot(data=data, x=x, y=y, kind='bar')
        ax.set_xlabels(x + ' ($ Millions)', size=15)
        plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
        ax.set_ylabels(y, size=15)
        ax.fig.suptitle(title, size=35)
```

This rendition now only ever returns the `if` statement, never going to the `else` statement even when there are values well over a million. I'm a bit confused why only the same part of the function works, even when the conditions are flipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the ordering of your condition.

This works:

```
(data[x]>1000000).any()
```

When you perform `data[x].any() > 1000000` you're asking Python:

Is there any `True` value in my columns? This can only get you a True (1) or a False(0).

Then you're asking:

Is 1 (or 0) greater than 1000000? This will be always False, so you always go to the `else` statement.

Hope this clears things up !

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, consider creating a new column with [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) that handles the million check and conversion directly in data frame using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) logical assignment. This would be the more pandemic (i.e., "pythonic" for pandas) solution as opposed to `if/else` blocks where Pandas Series is treated similar to Python list.

Also, below uses [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) instead of division symbol, `/`, with decimal rounding and `E` integer notation for 1 million (avoiding count of many zeroes). And code is DRY-er without repeating plot lines.

```
def bar_plot(data, x, y, title):
    sns.set_style('darkgrid')
    data = (data.sort_values(ascending=False, by=x)
                .head(n=10)
                # ASSIGN NEW COLUMN WITH CONVERSION
                .assign(val = lambda d: np.where((d[x] > 1E6).any(), d[x].div(1E6), d[x]).round(2))
                .reset_index(drop=True)
            )

    # ADJUST LABEL IF NO CONVERSION OCCURRED (CHECKING EQUALITY OF COLUMNS)
    xlab = x + ' ($ Millions)' if (data['val'].ne(data[x].round(2))).all() else x

    ax = sns.catplot(data=data, x='val', y=y, kind='bar')
    ax.set_xlabels(xlab, size=15)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
    ax.set_ylabels(y, size=15)
    ax.fig.suptitle(title, size=35)

    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

To demonstrate on random data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(121119)
data = pd.DataFrame({'dep': np.random.uniform(1, 5E5, 15),
                     'num1': np.random.randint(1, 10, 15),         # NO VALUES OVER 1 MILLION
                     'num2': np.random.normal(2, 1, 15),           # NO VALUES OVER 1 MILLION
                     'num3': np.random.randint(1E3, 1E7, 15)       # MANY VALUES OVER 1 MILLION
                    })

bar_plot(data, 'num2', 'dep', 'my title')
bar_plot(data, 'num3', 'dep', 'my title')
```

[image: First Plot Output]

[image: Second Plot Output]

Comment: Thank you for providing this new perspective! I figured there had to be a way to do it without essentially rewriting the same code in both the `if/else` statements, I just didn't know how to approach it.